# windows based .Net Application migration to Azure

Tags: azure, migration, windows

I have a windows application which reads files from multiple FTP location and process them and stores the data into Oracle database. its running as scheduled task in on-premise. requirement is to move this to Azure...

since i am new to azure , not able to decide which is the right choice (Logic app, azure function, scheduled task, worker role etc )?.

please guide me.

thanks!!

Comment: This question is very broad and does not have a definite answer.. there are many ways to achieve what you want to do. For example, if it's some legacy application, doing a lift-and-shift to a VM might be the only option (we don't know your app). If you are doing a rewrite, then use the alternatives you list are viable options. In my opinion, the answer depends a lot on your requirements and your business needs.

Comment: Hi Kim, Thanks for your reply. This is not a legacy code, its .net based windows application (not a console application) and it does all the operation in form_load, so they have scheduled using exe.  you consider it as rewrite and suggest me best approach to move.

Comment: If you can use passive mode with those FTP hosts, you could re-write for Azure Functions or as a WebJob in App Service. If you need to connect to those hosts in FTP active mode, pretty much VM is your only option since you'll need to open a s**** of ports.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your inputs...